# memcached or MongoDB to relieve heavy database calls

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, memcached

Lately my site has been getting about 2.5 million hits per day (on average). I record hits to each and every page (it's an adult site), so I'm able to have a Top 10 sort of thing that shows top Websites, Models, Galleries and Images. I record the hit, as well as the users IP so those individual sections only get incremented one time per user, every 24 hours. The problem with this is that it's updating the mysql database each hit. So of course, my site has started getting 504 errors.

I looked around and saw that memcached might be a solution. Store hits in memory and push to the database every X mins. I also saw some people suggest using MongoDB, which to my understanding is also a memory type storage. Would this be the way to go? Would you recommend memcached or MongoDB for what I'm trying to do? Or is this not the way to proceed because it just means more mysql calls in a shorter time frame (1 huge batch, say, every minute would mean 60 seconds worth of hits versus smaller batches every second).

I have both memcached and MongoDB installed on my server, so either is an option.

Answer (score 1):

there may be much easier solutions to obtain better database performance without new software packages. the volumes you mention are not particularly large. 
i'll list a just a few of many possibilities.
1. if you are on a version of mysql older than 5.6, then updating to 5.6+ will almost certainly yield a very significant improvement because the storage engine is much better for 5.6 and above.
2. if the busiest tables use a storage engine other than innodb, then switch to innodb. [you can do this with phpmyadmin]
3. get some help tuning buffer sizes in my.ini [it takes some skill] and/or increasing ram on the database server(s).
4. consider spreading the workload across more drives and/or switch part or all of the database to solid state drives  [or better conventional drives]
5. if the database server(s) is/are memory or compute bound then bigger or more servers may be needed.
6. make sure the bottleneck is not external to the database server(s).

Answer (score 0):

The way this site (stackoverflow.com) implements it is by maintaining in-memory data structure of question views which gets flushed to DB every 15 minutes or so. There is no need to stress DB by saving each hit - too much IO. This in-memory structure could be just within your application as a map of ip and hits/time or it could be in memcached. I don't think you really need memcached for this purpose.
So the general idea to do batch updates that you had is a good one.